# What kind of PC address could be in memory other than function entry point and return address?

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

The program counter (PC) value/address (like the value in %RIP on x86_64) could be in memory for some reasons (direct call/jump instructions in .text segment are not considered):

1. Function pointers.
2. Function return address in stack.
3. Jump table (switch/case in C, method dispatch in C++).
4. Context restoration: setjmp/longjmp, C++ exception handling, ptrace, getcontext, siglongjmp, signal delivery/sigreturn.

In kernel,

5. Interrupt return address.
6. Page fault handler, restartable atomic sequences (RAS) registry.
7. Thread/process context structure, like Task state segment (TSS), task_struct.

What other possible usage for PC address stored in memory, other than function entry pointer (e.g., function pointer), for different operating systems, on AMD64/i386/ARM?

Also, is there any form of encodings for these addresses?

For example, in jump tables, on x86_64, compiler could use 32-bit offset instead of 64-bit full address. In glibc's setjmp/longjmp jmp_buf, they use a special encoding (PTR_MANGLE) for the saved register values.

Comment: Code for conditional/unconditional jumps? Every loop and every conditional has at least one.

Comment: Direct jump/call are not considered since they are in .text segment.

Comment: OK. I guess user-space ("green") threads fall under #4? If so, I think you've covered everything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Green thread is the one managed by VM in userspace, right?

Comment: If a process uses ptrace (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) to control another then it will have the other's PC somewhere in memory, same for interpreters like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org/) and code instrumentation like Intel's Pintools (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @user3344003 What can other possibilities be?

Comment: In general, a PC can reference ANY address in memory (van Nueman machine).

Comment: yes. people can hard code any address into a pointer. I mean, real world usage examples.

Comment: @amdn So probably other interpreter-like runtime environment and debug tools also have, like Python intepreter, JVM, right?

Comment: @WindChaser: there is a difference between native code and bytecode. The bytecode in a virtual machine is *data* to be interpreted by the interpreter, in that sense a pointer to the "next bytecode to interpret" is really just a data pointer.  A true program counter (instruction pointer) "PC or IP" contains a pointer to native instructions, it is an address that the CPU can start fetching from and execute native instructions in the context of a kernel or user space thread.